# Distinguish between Local IP and WAN IP by using C++ or C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I want to write a function with the feature is described as below

```
bool isLocalIp(String _ip);
_ip: The string with a ip format or a domain format (ex: 112.42.11.44 or http://abc.def.com/)
Return: True if the _ip is Local IP, False if _ip is WAN IP
```

I have searched but I did not find any topic about this.
Someone can show me how to write this function?

Many thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local IP vs. WAN IP is a poorly defined concept (at best). Just for example, a VPN connection can give a "local" IP address to a computer that's connected via a WAN.

That said, the basic idea is fairly simple. The subnet mask is intended for precisely this purpose. You typically start with your local IP address, and find whether some other address is local to it. To do that, you `and` each address with the subnet mask, the compare the results. If they're not equal, they're on different subnets.

Note, however, that a machine may be multi-homed, meaning it has two or more adapters, each of which could be on a different subnet. So, you really want to get a list of all the local adapters, and check the address against each.

That may or may not mean it's really a WAN connection though. Just for example, on a campus of a decent sized company you might have a number of subnets that are all local at least least some degree.

For a typical home user, however, this will work just fine. Everything on his side of the router will use the local subnet, and everything on the other side of the router will have some address outside the local subnet.

In C++, you can get a list of adapters and the address and subnet mask for each with [`GetIpAddrTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949.aspx).

This all depends on your working with a numeric IP address. If you have a domain name instead, you'll first need to first resolve it to a numeric IP address, such as with [`gethostbyname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524.aspx) or [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx).

Also note that what I've described above is really for IPv4. IPv6 sort of has a vaguely similar concept, but the details are enough different it'll almost certainly require separate code.

Comment: Thank You! Jerry Coffin.

Answer (score 1):

Local IPs are usually private IPs, and therefore in the range of `10.x.x.x`, `192.168.x.x`, and `172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255`

However, the local IP can just as well be a public IP, in which case you'd need to do something like `tracert` and interpret the results.